# Antiderivative of $\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{16-2^{2x}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, exponential-function, substitution

I need help solving for this integral:
$$\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{16-2^{2x}}}dx.$$

I tried using trigonometric substitution, but I wasn't able to solve it in that way ( I didn't get anything "friendly").

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex%2Fsqrt(16-2%5E(2x))) gives a result in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: There is no closed form solution, unfortunately, WA gives a result in terms of the hypergeometric series.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean 
$$\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{16-e^{2x}}}dx$$
then $e^x=4\cos{t}$ helps.

Comment: I thought perhaps a typo. The alternative is unpalatable.

Comment: Do you mean a substitution $e^x = 4 \cos t$?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$2^{2x}=e^{\ln\left(2^{2x}\right)}=\left(e^x\right)^{\ln 4}$$
So:
$$\int{\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{16-2^{2x}}}}dx=\int{\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{16-\left(e^x\right)^{\ln 4}}}}dx$$ 
Now:$$u=e^x,~du=e^x dx$$
So you get
$$\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-u^{\ln 4}}}}du$$
Now, unless you know VERY complicated things(the hypergeometric function) you can't do it, maybe you copied the function wrong?

Comment: Your result is effectively the same as the OP, your answer is of no greater value than the comments under the OP. It may be worthwhile how you know from going from you transformed integral leads to a solution in, say, $_2F_1$

Comment: @Kevin if the OP do know hypergeometric function than changing the integral to that form will help him